# Does GoogleTagManager API exposes values as well?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager-server-side

TGM documentation shows we can get a list of all the variables, but not their values.

Is there a way to get all the values of each var?

https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/api/v2/reference#Variables

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that what you see in GTM is not code at runtime. GTM is just a way to configure logic. GTM itself has no clue what happens on pages. It also does not receive any data from the pages.

As such, its API has no idea what tags are triggered, what variables are used, or what values are stored there.

The API, however, allows you to get all the meta data about the variables. You can get their type, you can see where they're referenced, you can see what's hardcoded in them or what code they execute.

Why do you need to know the values of the variables to be available via the API? Looks like you're trying to solve a problem with an inappropriate tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want to build a monitoring tool that notifies about new values that the RnD group puts and the Markerting group are not aware of. Isn't it possible with TGM rest API?

Comment: RnD doesn't tell me much. If you need to monitor something on the pages, you should monitor it in the places the variables take the data from. Typically, the dataLayer. But depends on variables. Can be DOM, can be cookies, or query params. Depends on the particular vars you want to keep track of.

Comment: We mostly want to count user-defined vars "purchase" with value = X. Sometimes the website developers change the value to Y, so our counting is dropping and we want to be notified var "purchase" has a new value which is different than expected value "X".

Comment: when you say var "purchase" what kind of var is that?

Comment: user defined var: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXGq3.png

Comment: yeah, those are dataLayer variables. If you need to check their values, write a script that would load in parallel or from GTM and get the value from the dataLayer object directly. Or get them from GA if GTM sends it there. Or better yet, export your GA into BQ and inspect raw values sent.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but how would you do that `"If you need to check their values, write a script that would load in parallel or from GTM and get the value from the dataLayer object directly"` ?Check their value in the webpage and send console error? because I prefer an external automation. how would you write this?

Comment: well I would probably just check BQ's raw data. There's no need to track these values again if they're already tracked. Another approach would be to deploy a script that would maybe override the dataLayer's .push() method exactly how GTM does it, then in there, I would do all the checks I need and send the results to whatever endpoint I want them at.

Comment: Thanks! `.push() method exactly how GTM does it, then in there, I would do all the checks I need` but then how do you notify the user when the values are not as expected? It's not the website user but a markerter person

Comment: if the values are not as expected, you communicate with the department who's responsible for those values. If the values are wrong in the dataLayer, that's usually up to the front-end development team to resolve.

Comment: We want to use a GTM template that does some validation and throws an error accordingly.

How can we email-notify when google-TagManager (client) for a specific error?


```
> GTM Error:  {"version":"1.1","eventName":"gtm.load","eventId":0,"dataLayerKey":"ecommerce.impressions.0.name","variableName":"Variable Name","error":{"value":"14 Day Challenge - Starts March 9th","condition":"notType","conditionValue":"string"}}

```

Comment: we've went here through a couple of different questions. Now this question is completely unrelated to the original topic, please make a separate question.

Comment: I have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77821038/how-can-we-email-notify-when-google-tagmanager-client-for-a-specific-error