# How can we email-notify when google-TagManager (client) for a specific error?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-tag-manager-server-side

We want to use a GTM template that does some validation and throws an error accordingly.

How can we email-notify when google-TagManager (client) for a specific error?

```
> GTM Error:  {"version":"1.1","eventName":"gtm.load","eventId":0,"dataLayerKey":"ecommerce.impressions.0.name","variableName":"Variable Name","error":{"value":"14 Day Challenge - Starts March 9th","condition":"notType","conditionValue":"string"}}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a backend instance for it. You don't send emails by front-end only. There has to be an smtp server. This question goes into more depth: [How to send an email from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381150/how-to-send-an-email-from-javascript)

GTM template or just custom HTML tag would do though something like this would   normally be hosted with the front-end. Either way, your JS would conduct the checks you need, then contact the backend endpoint or API to send the email.

Email itself is a very unconventional way of tracking errors. Since you're already in GTM, it would be way easier to just send a GA event when errors occur using a CJS variable in the error trigger.

Comment: What simpler notification way would you recommend for failing tests of this template?

Comment: send GA events then use your normal analytics reporting to pull them.

Comment: Thanks, the default now is outputing to the browser console? `newError(value, table[i].condition, table[i].conditionValue);`

Comment: `send GA events then use your normal analytics reporting to pull them` but this won't be online/real-time notifications. No?

Comment: Yeah, that wouldn't be real-time. For real-time you have no choice but to have a dedicated server listening for calls, or maybe a SAAS that does it for you.